# CRITICAL BUG in HERE API: autosuggest ignores result_types parameter since today

Tags: here-api, autosuggest, here-maps-rest

Today the autosuggest endpoint of the HERE API (https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/autosuggest) started ignoring the `result_types` parameter.

Example: if you make a get request to /autosuggest with `result_types=place,address` you still get results with `"type": "urn:nlp-types:autosuggest"`.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug.

Please check 'resultType' property in a response instead of 'type'

[image]

Documentation on https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics_api/media-type-autosuggest.html

There you can see:

> type: All Autosuggest place and address results have type
> 'urn:nlp-types:place'

> resultType: The type of Autosuggest result item which can be 'place'
> for a Place and 'address' for an Address